Model class's members are not being set by Form fields
I have the following SwiftData model:
import SwiftData
import Foundation

@Model
final class CollectionModel {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var name: String = ""
}


And in my view I declare it as a @Bindable, in this way:
@Bindable var collectionStore: CollectionModel = CollectionModel()

And then in my View I create my form like this:
Form {
            Text("Add Collection")
            TextField("Name", text: $collectionStore.name)            
            Button("Save", action: self.saveCollection)
        }.alert(self.formAlertMessage, isPresented: self.$formShowAlert, actions: {
            Button(LocalizedStringKey("Ok"), role: .cancel) {}
        })

But when I save the form, the variables are empty. I have checked that via debugger.

Did you ever insert the model into the ModelContext? Did you even create a ModelContainer?

I insert it and save it. But the point is before the modelContext issue, the point is the values are not assigned to the members of the @Bindable class (regardless of saving and insertion action happens afterward or not)

@Bindable should only be used for objects that are created (owned) and passed from a parent view but you are creating the model object inside the view so it’s not needed (and even wrong) here.

@JoakimDanielson So how should I use the model inside the view directly?

Change Bindable to State

Or maybe even let

Has this been resolved?

It has, yes. The issue was in Entry point the Item.self was not set in Model container (the actual model name instead of Item)
